# Undefined Variable 'os' pylint(undefined-variable) [57,18]

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, pylint

I am stuck here and dont know why  this error is occuring.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvz5g.png)

Comment: you need to import os

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see this post as to why posting images of code is not considered good practice: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I have the same problem. The 'import os' helped me. I don't know why this question is downvoted...

Answer (score 5):

Add `import os` to your **settings.py**